# Spring boot, db resilience

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

My goal is to make my app resilent for db connection issues (used db postgres)
So I have the following config:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASS}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=1
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=${MAX_DB_CONNECTIONS}
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
```

This works as the application doesn't crash but the goal is that if the db connection is gone for less then 30 seconds, the rest calls work (with this config I get a 409 error when the db connection is not available), how to archive this?

Update:
The exception that I currently get:

```
SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@45614709 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:335)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:150)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:113)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2265)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2028)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1990)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:351)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2787)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2770)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2604)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2599)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2243)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1069)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1506)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy160.peekNullDomain(Unknown Source)
....
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:295)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1952)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
        ... 74 common frames omitted

2020-07-13 12:27:02.262  WARN 1 --- [taskScheduler-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08006
2020-07-13 12:27:02.262 ERROR 1 --- [taskScheduler-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
2020-07-13 12:27:02.263 ERROR 1 --- [taskScheduler-4] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Application exception overridden by rollback exception

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:254)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy160.peekNullDomain(Unknown Source)
        ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2265)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2028)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1990)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:351)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2787)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2770)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2604)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2599)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2243)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1069)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1506)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:335)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:150)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:113)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
        ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:295)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1952)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
        ... 74 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What would you do when there is no connection? Return data from the cache?

Comment: Let the request hang for up to 30 seconds to see if the connection comes back, so that the only thing that use user notices is that the call is a bit slow

Comment: Do you get any exceptions on the server side?

Comment: I found this post: https://html.developreference.com/article/27589601/Does+HikariCP+supports+command+timeout+in+Spring+Boot+application+similar+to+C%23 it seems that what i want is what they call in C# command timeout